# What controls break before member function of an object in clang format?

Tags: clang-format

This is the part of of C++ code I want to format with clang-format tool (version 7.0.0).

```cxx
template <typename Fn>
void AsyncAPI::init_write(std::string const& data, Fn&& callback)
{
    errorcode injected(injected_);
    injected_ = 0;

    if (!injected) { data_ = data; }
    std::thread([injected, callback = std::forward<Fn>(callback)]() mutable {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
        callback(injected);
    })
        .detach();
}
```

The `detach()` member function of `this_thread` is somehow moved to a new line. How can I move it one line up, so it looks like

```cxx
std::thread([]() {
/*
*/
}).detach();
```

I've quite content with current settings, so I hope the change is not too drastic. I tried predefined format styles provided by `clang-format` (Google, LLVM), none of them was able to move `detach` up.

My clang-format config file is,

```
---
Language:        Cpp
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: false
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: true
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true
AlignEscapedNewlines: Left
AlignOperands:   true
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: All
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeComma
BreakInheritanceList: BeforeComma
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass: true
  AfterControlStatement: true
  AfterFunction: true
  AfterNamespace: true
  AfterStruct: true
  AfterUnion: true
  BeforeCatch: true
  BeforeElse: false
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
BreakStringLiterals: true
ColumnLimit:     80
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: true
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: false
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat:   false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
FixNamespaceComments: true
ForEachMacros:   [ foreach, Q_FOREACH, BOOST_FOREACH ]
IncludeBlocks: Regroup
IndentCaseLabels: false
IndentWidth:     4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: true
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: Inner
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 19
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 60
PointerAlignment: Left
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles:  false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard:        Cpp11
TabWidth:        4
UseTab:          Never
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be something that broke in `clang-format` version 5.0.0, and was fixed for version 10.0.0 (verified using the [configurator](https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/)). So, your best bet is to move to `clang-format` version 10.0.0 or later.